# Loading data from shapefiles into specific feature classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I am trying to bulk load a collection of shapefiles into empty feature classes in ArcMap 10.2.  The issue here is that the names of the shapefiles and the feature classes need to match up.  Is there any way to make this happen in Model Builder or arcpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this tool [Feature Class To Feature Class (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000), the help section contains sample scripts if you want to go the arcpy path.

Right clicking on the tool reveals a "batch" option, you can set the names how you want.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that.  I was overthinking the problem trying to use model builder to figure something out.  Thanks a lot, that was a bit of a rookie mistake.